# Excel positives values to red

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

i need custom text format to highlight positive values to red.
I see that there is custom format for negative values in red, but i cant figure out what should i do to highlight positive values to red.

Something like this is for highlighting negative values in red

```
# ##0,00\ _€;[Red]-# ##0,00\ _€
```

thanks

Comment: try conditional formatting option if you using Excel-2010 or above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will put positive values in red and negative in default color.

```
[Red]#,##0;-#,##0
```

Comment: The syntax is in the form of `<positive value format>[;<negative value format>[;<zero value format>[;<string>]]]` and therefore putting `[Red]` before the first semi-colon will make positive value red.